# Angular JS AJAX Call with Parameters

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, parameters

without the parameters of the method Get, the code works, but if the method asks for a parameter an error 404 is returned. How do I properly send parameters with Angular JS?

```
factory.test = function () {
    var q = $q.defer();

    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: url + "/dataEntry/test",
        data: {
            sampletext : "sample"
        }
    })
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
            q.resolve(data);
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
            q.reject(data);
        });

    return q.promise;
};
```

---

```
    [Route("test")] 
    public String Get(string sampletext)
    { 
        return "Reply coming from data entry controller" + sampletext; 
    }
```

Comment: What is your backed ? ASP.Net MVC ?

Comment: Yes it is. ASP .Net MVC

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since it's a GET request you shouldn't be sending data. You need to be sending a query string.

Change your `data` to `params`.

```
$http({
    method: "GET",
    url: url + "/dataEntry/test",
    params: {
        sampletext : "sample"
    }
})
```

Source: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http)

Answer (score -2):

```
$http({
    url: "/saveInfo",
    method: 'Post'
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log("saved successfully");
}, function(response) {
    console.log("Error message");   
});
```